# iOS Keyboard Partial Trigger on input focus

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile, web-chat

When the using the site in Safari on iPhone 5/SE, focusing on either of the two inputs shown below doesn't fully trigger the keyboard. The field toggle and "Done" buttons appear but no keyboard.

We're using a third party chat plugin that we can't swap out for another one.

The live site is: https://www.citywesthousingtrust.org.uk

I'm using the iOS simulator here but it works the same on the physical devices we have too. The issue appears to be limited to iPhone 5/SE.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot showing partial keyboard initiation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator does this because you have a physical keyboard on your mac so no need to display anything (you can type using your computer keyboard).

If you explicitly need the iOS keyboard to show up, press 'command + K' when you're in the simulator

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I've disabled the hardware keyboard from the menus and it's showing now. I've spent waaay too much on this issue :-(

Comment: Glad it worked! I faced this issue before while doing a custom keyboard imagine that! (PS: command+K is the shortcut to disable the hardware keyboard)